# Java Runtime.getRuntime.exec() returns null but returns valid String in shell

Tags: java, linux, shell, runtime.exec

I've been writing a class to find the real userID, using the linux binary `/usr/bin/logname` that returns the current user associated with my TTY. The command works fine in shell.

```
/usr/bin/logname
scott
```

But I cannot get the same as a String in java with the following code that I wrote.

```
private String currentUser;
public void getRealUser() throws Exception{
        String cmd = "/usr/bin/logname";
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        this.currentUser = stdInput.readLine();
        System.out.println(currentUser);
}
```

When I create the object, I am seeing `null` for the value `currentUser`, which means `stdInput.readLine();` is not outputting anything.

Please let me know what am I doing wrong.

Comment: I have a similar app, but I read the input before `p.waitFor();`  Have you tried putting `p.waitFor();` before the `System.out.println` ?

Comment: Yes. It is still `null` with `p.waitFor()` after `System.out.println()`

Comment: I meant after the `this.currentUser =` statement, but before the `System.out.` statement. On another note, there's the potential that the first line you get is a null line... I use a while loop to make sure I read all lines from the `InputStream`.

Comment: Works correctly for me...

Comment: have you tried what the output of `p.getErrorStream()` is? I get `no login name` on stderr when I run that when I'm not actually logged in remotely (I get a result after `ssh localhost`)

Comment: @zapl Yes, it is giving me the same output when capturing the `ErrorStream.`. I tested `logname` to see if the output goes to `STDOUT` or `STDERR`, and it goes to `STDERR` only.

Comment: What about exitcode from `waitFor` and maybe new ProcessBuilder? http://ideone.com/IEyChV

Comment: @Jan I am running this from both my IDE, and my bash shell. It is a debian bash shell with all the default variable. Please let me know if you are specifically looking for some environment variables.

Comment: @zapl Thank you, but I am still getting `/usr/bin/logname: no login name
Done.` when run from java, but getting `scott` if I run from shell.

Comment: @Jan that was the one from the ideone.com link 4 comments above. - scott that's not a java problem, I get the same error in the terminal in some cases. The error means something like: your shell command runs in a login shell while the java one doesn't (the subprocess spawned from the java one). Or http://aplawrence.com/Forum/TonyLawrence8.html - in other words, linux sometimes doesn't know how the user is that's responsible for a process $LOGNAME or $USERNAME orso may have a value but they aren't reliable either

Comment: Thanks a lot @zapl I will customise my shell to get this working then. And the link that explains about `controlling terminal of the process ` makes perfect sense why this was not working. If you can update this as the answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not answering your question directly, but did you try :

```
System.getProperty("user.name")
```

which is at least platform agnostic?  Why bother writing code thats unix specific in a language like Java?

Comment: Yes, that will, but that will defeat the purpose of getting the real username, but returns the effective username. If I run the program as sudo, it will return root, but if I run `/usr/bin/logname` as sudo, it will return the real user, not root.